# funds in hd wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet-recovery, bip32-hd-wallets, deterministic-wallets

I have a doubt on HD wallets, I have generated a sequence of address.

1. how to check the balance of each address or how we can look for balance.
2. Did the amount move to the base address as like monero eg. the funds once send to the integrated address it will move the base address.
3. How to restore the wallet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any answer for below question

```-Then how exchange are moving funds if they are using HD wallets. They manual move all the funds to cold storage. If they manual, how they can bare the transaction fee. – ```

Answer (score 1):

> How to check the balance of each address or how we can look for balance?

You will have to scan the blockchain and find the UTXOs that are locked with your addresses in the locking script. You can either do that by running a full node by downloading and verifying the blockchain yourself, or run a Simplified Payment Verification (SPV) node and query other nodes using bloom filters. You can also use Electrum and import the addresses to create a watch-only wallet.

> Did the amount move to the base address as like monero eg. the funds once send to the integrated address it will move the base address?

There is no funds "moving" to base addresses. Only the private key that can unlock the UTXO will be able to spend the bitcoins. Generally, when you import your HD seed into any standard wallet, it will start generating child keys and scan the blockchain to see if there are any UTXOs that can be controlled by these child keys.

> How to restore the wallet?

Just backup the mnemonic or the seed that was used to generate the child keys and addresses. Any standard wallet will be able to generate addresses if you have the seed.

Comment: for second, how it can be achieved.

Comment: @Sarath - you mean SPV node or Electrum wallet?

Comment: -Then how exchange are moving funds if they are using HD wallets. They manual move all the funds to cold storage. If they manual, how they can bare the transaction fee.

Comment: '''when you import your HD seed into any standard wallet, it will start generating child keys and scan the blockchain to see if there are any UTXOs that can be controlled by these child keys''' does this men, when a seed is provided , the wallet will start deriving child addresses, and start crawling  blockchain to see if any of the transaction is intendent to that address?

Comment: @cryptoKTM If it is a full node, it already has the UTXO database so it can directly query the UTXO set. So the full node will generate the child addresses and query this UTXO set. If it is a SPV node, it would query information from connected full nodes using bloom filters,